# Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported] Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-post, http-status-code-405

I created a sample crud operations application using Spring Mvc, Hibernate, Maven. All my operations are working fine. I got a problem on update method. I dont know where I went wrong. I referred this article. https://java2blog.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-crud-example/

Add,delete, display methods are working fine.
Here is the issue I am getting when I try to update.
WARNING: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
I do not know what's wrong. Please help
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmvi9.png)

Controller Class:

```
package com.spring.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.spring.bean.Person;
import com.spring.service.PersonService;

@Controller
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService service;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllPersons", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String getPerson(Model model) {
 
        List<Person> listOfPersons = service.getAllPersons();
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        model.addAttribute("listOfPersons", listOfPersons);
        return "PersonDetails";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPerson/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getPerson(id);
    }
    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person) {

        if(person.getId()==0) {
            service.addPerson(person);
        }
        else {
            service.updatePerson(person);
        }
        
        return "redirect:/getAllPersons";
    }
    
    //@RequestMapping(value = "/updateCountry/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("person", this.service.getPerson(id));
        model.addAttribute("listOfPersons", this.service.getAllPersons());
        return "PersonDetails";
    }
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deletePerson/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public String deletePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        service.deletePerson(id);
        return "redirect:/getAllPersons";
    }
}
```

Dao Class:

```
package com.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.bean.Person;

@Repository
public class PersonDao {
     
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionfactory;
    
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionfactory = sf;
    }
    
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        Session session=this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> persons= session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        
        for(Person p:persons) {
            System.out.print(p.getName()+" "+p.getCountry());
        }
        
        return persons;
        
    }
    
    public Person getPerson(int id) {
        Session session=this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println("Here");
        Person p=(Person)session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        System.out.println(p);
        return p;
    }
    
    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        Session session=this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        session.persist(person);
        return person;
    }
    
    public void updatePerson(Person person) {
        Session session=this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        session.update(person);
    }
    
    public void deletePerson(int id) {
        Session session=this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        
        Person p=session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        if(null!= p) {
            session.delete(p);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Jsp Page:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Person Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person" action="addPerson">
<table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Add Person</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <form:hidden path="id" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><form:label path="name">Name:</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="name" size="30" maxlength="30"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td><form:label path="country">Country:</form:label></td>
          <td><form:input path="country" size="30" maxlength="30"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                class="blue-button" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<hr>
  <h3>Person List</h3>
<c:if test="${!empty listOfPersons}">
    <table class="tg">
    <tr>
        <th width="80">Id</th>
        <th width="120">Person Name</th>
        <th width="120">Country</th>
        <th width="60">Edit</th>
        <th width="60">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach items="${listOfPersons}" var="person">
        <tr>
            <td>${person.id}</td>
            <td>${person.name}</td>
            <td>${person.country}</td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='updatePerson/${person.id}' />" >Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="<c:url value='deletePerson/${person.id}' />" >Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is only accepting `GET` requests. You need to change it to `POST` as follows:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatePerson/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id,Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", this.service.getPerson(id));
    model.addAttribute("listOfPersons", this.service.getAllPersons());
    return "PersonDetails";
}
```

Nevertheless, you should consider using `PUT` for update requests so that you follow the standards. You can read more at https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html.

Comment: I did this change. But I am getting an exception that GET request is not supported. I also put POST ans GET together. Still getting error.

Comment: That makes no sense. Your initial error was `Request method 'POST' not supported` and I suggested you to change the code as above and now you are getting the same but for `GET`? DId you change the code in the right place? Are you calling the endpoint in any other place?

Comment: Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]...... I am getting this exception and yes i did the same changes as you mentioned....

Comment: But then where are you calling the endpoint `/updatePerson/{id}` with a `GET`? You must call it as a `POST` request...

Comment: Yes i did it in the controller. Changed the method type to post. But then I got the above exception.

Comment: That is not my question. Where in your JSPs you are calling the endpoint `/updatePerson/{id}` with a `GET`? You must use `POST` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had csrf enabled in my sprint security xml file, so I just added one line in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

This way I was able to submit the form having the model attribute.